# CounterMutationStage and ViewMutationStage metrics are missing in Cassandra 4.0

Tags: cassandra, jmx, nodetool, cassandra-4.0

When invoking `nodetool tpstats` on Cassandra 4.0, here is what I got [nodetool result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUqZo.png)

But no CounterMutationStage and ViewMutationStage found.  Where are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the good work that have been done by Cassandra developers, the metrics are now lazy initialised to improve the performance.

The best way to "wake up" all lazy metrics is:

```
nodetool getconcurrency
```

Answer (score 0):

Those metrics are still there.  The issue though, is that they expose their data "lazily."  Which basically means, they won't show at all when the value is zero.  Once you start writing to counters or views, those metrics execute their "lazy initialization," and only then are they exposed.  I tested this out using Cassandra 4.0 beta4.

Running a baseline `nodetool tpstats | head -n 4`:

```
Pool Name                    Active Pending Completed Blocked All time blocked
MutationStage                0      0       1         0       0
ReadStage                    0      0       27        0       0
CompactionExecutor           0      0       41        0       0
```

Next, I'll create a simple counter table.

```
CREATE TABLE games_popularity (game text PRIMARY KEY, popularity counter);
```

I'll increment the counter a few times and `SELECT` it.

```
aploetz@cqlsh> SELECT * FROM stackoverflow.games_popularity ;

 game           | popularity
----------------+------------
 Cyberpunk 2077 |          3

(1 rows)
```

Now rerunning the `nodetool tpstats | head -n 4` indeed show `CounterMutationStage`:

```
Pool Name                    Active Pending Completed Blocked All time blocked
MutationStage                0      0       12        0       0
CounterMutationStage         0      0       3         0       0
ReadStage                    0      0       96        0       0
```

Note that in 4.0 these metrics are also exposed in the `system_view.thread_pools` virtual table, which you can view with `SELECT * FROM system_views.thread_pools;`.

Comment: G'day mate, thanks heaps for your answer!

Comment: I was inspired by your approach to CounterMutationStage metric, so I did some operations on materialized views to obtain ViewMutationCount:

create a base table -> create a materialised view table based on the base table -> insert some table in the base table -> select * from view table -> update some data in the base table -> select * from view table -> delete some data in the base table -> select * from view table 

but I still can't see "ViewMutationStage" metric in "nodetool tpstats", what you reckon mate? 

Many thanks!